# How to get the text on qpushbutton?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I am loading .ui files via QUiloader, and showing the GUI in my application.

```
QWidget *mywidget = loader.load(file, this);
QList<QWidget*> wlist = mywidget.findChildren<QWidget *>()
```

I would like to know what is the text on QPushbutton. I know there is a method text() to get a text from Pushbutton, but it is not accessible when I do:

```
QString btext = wlist.at(1).text();
```

Any idea how I can get the text from QPushbutton, and other Widgets, when they grouped as QWidget?

Thanks.

Comment: Try casting from QWidget to QPushButton, then you can use the QPushButton::text() function.

Comment: I did cast it. Thanks.

Comment: Which cast do you use?

Comment: I cast like this: dynamic_cast<QPsuhButton *>(wlist).text();

Comment: I think qobject_cast<>() is a bit faster (at least it was in Qt4.0.0) but that's fine. Anyway don't forget to check for nullptr afterwards.

Comment: I am sorry, can you please explain what nullptr and how should I check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should search for QPushButtons instead of QWidgets:

```
QList<QPushButton*> blist = widget.findChildren<QPushButton*>();
```

Still your code wouldn't compile. The last line should read:

```
QString btext = blist.at(1)->text();
```

Using `->` since you are accessing a pointer, not the widget. Also you should check if the findChildren() function actually returnes enough buttons. You would get a crash or assertions when accessing a list item by an invalid index.

Also please note that `at(1)` does not return the first but the second item in the list (lists start from 0).

Update: If you search for QWidgets and cast each of them you need to take care of getting a nullptr:

```
QList<QWidget*> wlist = widget.findChildren<QWidget*>();
foreach (QWidget* w, wlist)
{
   QPushButton* b = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(w);
   // If "w" is not a button "b" is nullptr
   if (b)
   {
      QString btext = b->text();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I need to get all the widgets, therefore I did so. at(1), I copied from my code from loop, sorry.